# Calling CreateProcessAsUser from C#

Tags: c#, winapi, process, privileges, createprocessasuser

I've been attempting to create a new process under the context of a specific user using the `CreateProcessAsUser` function of the Windows API, but seem to be running into a rather nasty security issue...

Before I explain any further, here's the code I'm currently using to start the new process (a console process - PowerShell to be specific, though it shouldn't matter).

```
    private void StartProcess()
    {
        bool retValue;

        // Create startup info for new console process.
        var startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
        startupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(startupInfo);
        startupInfo.dwFlags = StartFlags.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        startupInfo.wShowWindow = _consoleVisible ? WindowShowStyle.Show : WindowShowStyle.Hide;
        startupInfo.lpTitle = this.ConsoleTitle ?? "Console";

        var procAttrs = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        var threadAttrs = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        procAttrs.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(procAttrs);
        threadAttrs.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(threadAttrs);

        // Log on user temporarily in order to start console process in its security context.
        var hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        var hUserTokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
        var pEnvironmentBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
        var pNewEnvironmentBlock = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (!WinApi.LogonUser("UserName", null, "Password",
            LogonType.Interactive, LogonProvider.Default, out hUserToken))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Error logging on user.");

        var duplicateTokenAttrs = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        duplicateTokenAttrs.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(duplicateTokenAttrs);
        if (!WinApi.DuplicateTokenEx(hUserToken, 0, ref duplicateTokenAttrs,
            SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
            out hUserTokenDuplicate))
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Error duplicating user token.");

        try
        {
            // Get block of environment vars for logged on user.
            if (!WinApi.CreateEnvironmentBlock(out pEnvironmentBlock, hUserToken, false))
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(),
                    "Error getting block of environment variables for user.");

            // Read block as array of strings, one per variable.
            var envVars = ReadEnvironmentVariables(pEnvironmentBlock);

            // Append custom environment variables to list.
            foreach (var var in this.EnvironmentVariables)
                envVars.Add(var.Key + "=" + var.Value);

            // Recreate environment block from array of variables.
            var newEnvironmentBlock = string.Join("\0", envVars.ToArray()) + "\0";
            pNewEnvironmentBlock = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(newEnvironmentBlock);

            // Start new console process.
            retValue = WinApi.CreateProcessAsUser(hUserTokenDuplicate, null, this.CommandLine,
                ref procAttrs, ref threadAttrs, false, CreationFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE |
                CreationFlags.CREATE_SUSPENDED | CreationFlags.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
                pNewEnvironmentBlock, null, ref startupInfo, out _processInfo);
            if (!retValue) throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(),
                "Unable to create new console process.");
        }
        catch
        {
            // Catch any exception thrown here so as to prevent any malicious program operating
            // within the security context of the logged in user.

            // Clean up.
            if (hUserToken != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                WinApi.CloseHandle(hUserToken);
                hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            if (hUserTokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                WinApi.CloseHandle(hUserTokenDuplicate);
                hUserTokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            if (pEnvironmentBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                WinApi.DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnvironmentBlock);
                pEnvironmentBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            if (pNewEnvironmentBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNewEnvironmentBlock);
                pNewEnvironmentBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clean up.
            if (hUserToken != IntPtr.Zero)
                WinApi.CloseHandle(hUserToken);

            if (hUserTokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                WinApi.CloseHandle(hUserTokenDuplicate);

            if (pEnvironmentBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
                WinApi.DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnvironmentBlock);

            if (pNewEnvironmentBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pNewEnvironmentBlock);
        }

        _process = Process.GetProcessById(_processInfo.dwProcessId);
    }
```

For the sake of the issue here, ignore the code dealing with the environment variables (I've tested that section independently and it seems to work.)

Now, the error I get is the following (thrown at the line following the call to `CreateProcessAsUSer`):

> "A required privilege is not held by the client" (error code 1314)

(The error message was discovered by removing the message parameter from the Win32Exception constructor. Admittedly, my error handling code here may not be the best, but that's a somewhat irrelevant matter. You're welcome to comment on it if you wish, however.) I'm really quite confused as to the cause of this vague error in this situation. MSDN documentation and various forum threads have only given me so much advice, and especially given that the causes for such errors appear to be widely varied, I have no idea which section of code I need to modify. Perhaps it is simply a single parameter I need to change, but I could be making the wrong/not enough WinAPI calls for all I know. What confuses me greatly is that the previous version of the code that uses the plain `CreateProcess` function (equivalent except for the user token parameter) worked perfectly fine. As I understand, it is only necessary to call the Logon user function to receive the appropriate token handle and then duplicate it so that it can be passed to `CreateProcessAsUser`.

Any suggestions for modifications to the code as well as explanations would be very welcome.

### Notes

I've been primarily referring to the MSDN docs (as well as [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) for the C# function/strut/enum declarations). The following pages in particular seem to have a lot of information in the Remarks sections, some of which may be important and eluding me:

- [CreateProcessAsUser function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(VS.85).aspx)
- [LogonUser function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184(VS.85).aspx)
- [DuplicateTokenEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446617(VS.85).aspx)

## Edit

I've just tried out Mitch's suggestion, but unfortunately the old error has just been replaced by a new one: "The system cannot find the file specified." (error code 2)

The previous call to `CreateProcessAsUser` was replaced with the following:

```
retValue = WinApi.CreateProcessWithTokenW(hUserToken, LogonFlags.WithProfile, null,
    this.CommandLine, CreationFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE |
    CreationFlags.CREATE_SUSPENDED | CreationFlags.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
    pNewEnvironmentBlock, null, ref startupInfo, out _processInfo);
```

Note that this code no longer uses the duplicate token but rather the original, as the MSDN docs appear to suggest.

And here's another attempt using `CreateProcessWithLogonW`. The error this time is "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" (error code 1326)

```
retValue = WinApi.CreateProcessWithLogonW("Alex", null, "password",
    LogonFlags.WithProfile, null, this.CommandLine,
    CreationFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CreationFlags.CREATE_SUSPENDED |
    CreationFlags.CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, pNewEnvironmentBlock,
    null, ref startupInfo, out _processInfo);
```

I've also tried specifying the username in UPN format ("Alex@Alex-PC") and passing the domain independently as the second argument, all to no avail (identical error).

Comment: Don't ever pass your own description to Win32Exception.  Instead, pass a default-constructed Win32Exception as the InnerException of some exception type more appropriate for your function, your description goes in the outer exception.  That way the caller gets both your information (what failed) as well as the Win32 error code (how did it fail) and the unadulterated matching error message.

Comment: Is there any way to get a stdin/stdout from this process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ahh... seems liker I've been caught out by one of the biggest gotchas in WinAPI interop programming. Also, Posting the code for my function declarations would have been a wise idea in this case.

Anyway, all that I needed to do was add an argument to the DllImport attribute of the function specifying `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`. This did the trick for both the `CreateProcessWithLogonW` and `CreateProcessWithTokenW` functions. I guess it finally just hit me that the W suffix of the function names referred to Unicode and that I needed to explicitly specify this in C#! Here are the *correct* function declarations in case anyone is interested:

```
[DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CreateProcessWithLogonW(string principal, string authority,
    string password, LogonFlags logonFlags, string appName, string cmdLine,
    CreationFlags creationFlags, IntPtr environmentBlock, string currentDirectory,
    ref STARTUPINFO startupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo);

[DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(IntPtr hToken, LogonFlags dwLogonFlags,
    string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, CreationFlags dwCreationFlags,
    IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
    out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
```

Answer (score 6):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(VS.85).aspx):

> Typically, the process that calls the
>   CreateProcessAsUser function must have
>   the SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME and
>   SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME privileges. If
>   this function fails with
>   ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD (1314), use
>   the CreateProcessWithLogonW function
>   instead. CreateProcessWithLogonW
>   requires no special privileges, but
>   the specified user account must be
>   allowed to log on interactively.
>   Generally, it is best to use
>   CreateProcessWithLogonW to create a
>   process with alternate credentials.

See this blog post [How to call CreateProcessWithLogonW & CreateProcessAsUser in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2007/12/20/how-to-call-createprocesswithlogonw-createprocessasuser-in-net.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, CreateProcessWithLogonW isn't the solution for me given that I need to execute this code from within a Windows Service too, and as pointed out by one of the commenters on that blog post, it isn't possible.

Comment: (contd.) Maybe experimenting with some of the Local Security Policy rules will help, judging by the paragraph quoted in your post.

Comment: Note: I've updated the original post having tried your proposed solution.

Comment: Just noticed that I tried CreateProcessWithTokenW. No luck with CreateProcessAsLogonW: error 1326 (invalid logon credentials). Isn't this wonderful?... a completely unique error for each of the three functions.

Comment: @Noldorin: an error of "invalid logon credentials" seems fairly conclusive. Are you sure you have the Domain\username and password correct?

Comment: @Mitch: I would have thought so too, but it seems not (or perhaps I'm missing something obvious). The program is simply running on my local dev computer, so there shouldn't be any complications with domain.

Comment: (contd.) The following combinations of username/domain are tested and don't work: "Alex", null; "Alex", "Alex-PC"; "Alex@Alex-PC", null (error 1326, "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password"). Note that I've also updated my original post with the code. Thanks for the help so far...

Comment: I didn't test this, but probably should've used "PC\\Alex". That is the usual format when using user names in code-not the ones you were using.

Answer (score 5):

Jonathan Peppers
provided this great piece of code that fixed my issues

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0c0ca087-5e7b-4046-93cb-c7b3e48d0dfb?ppud=4

Comment: Should always avoid link-only answers. SO has a policy against that. This answer becomes useless without a summary of what is there and code sample if that link becomes broken (archived, etc.).

Comment: This code is magic! No body posts this piece of code to achieve password less launching of a process as a user. Thanks so much ermagana & the man himself - Jonathan Peppers! :)

Comment: Where is the said piece of code?!